# object HTMLDivElement coming while passing html code to php - Angular

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

**Brief Description:** We have html code in variable. We want to pass that code using `php` and save it in mysql.

`home.ts` side code:

```
this.divCodesub = document.getElementById(this.selectedDivCodesub);
console.log (this.divCodesub);
```

**Data in console.log is:**

```
<div id="0"><div id="change_color" class="heading-back context_menu"><div class="row"><div contenteditable="true" class="col-md-12 heading-sec context_menu">Hi there, Im <span contenteditable="true" class="head-clr">STACK</span></div><div contenteditable="true" class="col-md-12 heading-sec context_menu">Smart, simple and responsive.</div></div></div></div>
```

Now when we try to send using php, it is not saving. While saving, it converts html code into **divCode: [object HTMLDivElement]**, this message is seen in Network.

How can we pass it?

**Edit: 1**
How we are sending the variable to php, see code below -

`home.ts` code:

let params   =

```
    'divI='+this.list[this.selectedDivCodesub].div_id+'&divCode='+this.divCodesub;
            this._updateSection.callService(api,params).subscribe(data=>{
 ...
});
```

`service.ts` code:

```
 callService(api,params){
        var headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        return this._http.post(this._url+api,params+"&"+this.randomno,{headers:headers})
               .map((response:Response) => response.json());
    }
```

Comment: How do you "send" that variable?

Comment: Please post your service that makes the HTTP call.

Comment: question edited with service code, please have a look and suggest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the `outerHTML` property of an HTMLElement to convert it to string.

(open your console to see that it is indeed a string)

```js
const div = document.querySelector('div');
console.log(typeof div);
console.log(div.toString());
console.log(typeof div.outerHTML);
console.log(div.outerHTML);
```

```html
<div class="container">
  LOOK AT ME I'M A DIV
</div>
```

Comment: @user2828442 And obviously your variable contains an HTML element. so call `outerHTML` on your variable.

Comment: Alright I'll try the same and get back with my results